# Copying variable to clipboard creates a text box I don't need

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

I have an array that I would like to copy to the clipboard when I press the "c" key and do a left click on a button (see code below):

```js
        $(document).on('keydown', e => {
            $(document).on('click', d => {
                if (e.keyCode === 67) {
                    var dummyContent = [1, 2, 3];
                    var dummyContentTrue = dummyContent.join(', ');
                    var dummy = $('<input>').val(dummyContentTrue).appendTo('body').select()
                    document.execCommand('copy')
                }
            })
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As the code shows, it creates a LOT of textboxes which I cannot have on my page, and after I let go of "c", the boxes do not delete. I have tried `.remove()` on `$('<input>')`, but still to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated! (FYI in my code snippet, make sure to hold the letter c key and left click at the same time to see a result).

ALSO an FYI I only want the copy to happen when both the c key and left click are pressed. If c key is not pressed, I do not want it to copy the data.

Comment: Don't nest your event handlers (generally) - you're not saying "while keydown" you're saying "when a key goes down add another click handler".   so if you type "helloc" - you get 6 click handlers all of which fire as the last one was a `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.remove()` on an element or list of elements

So, it should be either be `$( "input" ).remove()`

Or, you can assign the newly created `input` to a variable and call `remove` on that element

```
var dummy = $('<input>'); // newly created element
dummy.val(dummyContentTrue).appendTo('body').select()
document.execCommand('copy')
dummy.remove() // remove the element
```

Also, every time you keydown, a new `click` handler is added to `document`. So you need to move it out of there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keydown` to record the key and `keyup` to clear the key (so it only works while holding down the key):

```js
var lastkey = 0;
$(document)
  .on('keydown', e => {
    lastkey = e.keyCode;
  })
  .on('keyup', e => {
    lastkey = 0;
  })
  .on('click', d => {
    console.log(lastkey)
    if (lastkey === 67) {
      var dummyContent = [1, 2, 3];
      var dummyContentTrue = dummyContent.join(', ');
      var dummy = $('<input>').val(dummyContentTrue).appendTo('body').select()
      document.execCommand('copy')
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```